# R Programming + FbOuth Issue + An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: r, facebook

I am able to successfully authenticate in facebook using R. Yet I am not able to access my basic details. The fbOuth file is created correctly as well

Code snippet and result

---

## Connect to facebook via app by default

```
library(Rfacebook)
finFacebookConnect <- function(type = "app")
{
  if(type == "app")
  {
     fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="288059621629308", 
                  app_secret="****",
                  extended_permissions = TRUE)
  }
  else if(type == "token")
  {
    # the code for the token connection to be added over here 
  }
  save(fb_oauth, file="fb_oauth")

}

load("fb_oauth")
```

**********All is fine this till point

```
me <- getUsers("me",token=fb_oauth)
```

---

Here I get an error
***"Error in callAPI(query, token) :
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"***.

I am not able to understand the cause of the same or how to resolve it. I tried multiple ways including the file access and issue check on the net

Your help or any direction to check is highly appreciated

Comment: If I recall correctly, FB's web services use _two_ tokens.  The first is the OAuth token, which you appear to have handled.  The second is an access token.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too. But I found the solution as below that you can refer.

http://www.listendata.com/2017/03/facebook-data-mining-using-r.html

If you have any problem please let me know.

have a nice everyday.

Frank